# Android MaterialButton not displaying correctly

Tags: android, material-design, androidx, material-components-android

I'm trying to use MaterialButton, but it doesnt'n work properly.
My androidx dependency

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha10'
```

my test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
        app:strokeColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And screenshot of my button, why style not working ??

[image]

Comment: Post your app theme

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Docs](https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/)

> Change your app theme to inherit from a *Material Components theme*

```
Theme.MaterialComponents
Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar
Theme.MaterialComponents.Light
Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar
Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar
Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight
Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar
Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar
```

> If you cannot change your theme to inherit from a *Material Components
>   theme*, you can inherit from a Material Components Bridge theme.

```
Theme.MaterialComponents.Bridge
Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Bridge
Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar.Bridge
Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge
Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar.Bridge
```

> *Bridge themes* inherit from *AppCompat themes*, but also define the new *Material Components theme* attributes for you.

Comment: Will it work on lower Android API ?? If i use this themes